# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[JobcounterComponent -> FetchJobDataService]

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting this error as shown in the screenshot below.

I have studied several similiar questions here. Most common suggestion is 'Add your service to your app module's providers array'. As I am writing web components with Angular elements, I do not actively use the default app component. However, I have added die Injectable property `providedIn: root` to the services decorator. IMO, this should be equivalent to adding the service to app module's providers array.

Have got no ideas on how to fix this.

Best, Dropbear.

My fetch-job-data.service.ts file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {count} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchJobDataService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getJobCount(jobCountUrl: string): Observable<{'count': number}> {

    return this._http.get<{'count': number}>(jobCountUrl);

  }

}
```

My jobcounter.component.js file:

```js
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FetchJobDataService} from '../../services/fetch-job-data.service';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './jobcounter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobcounter.component.scss']
})
export class JobcounterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public jobCount: {'count': number};
  public jobDataUrl = 'assets/data/jobCount.json';

  private complete$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private _fetchDataService: FetchJobDataService) {
    console.log('Job counter initialized...');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   this._fetchDataService.getJobCount(this.jobDataUrl)
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.complete$)
        )
        .subscribe(
          (jobCount) => {
            this.jobCount = jobCount;
            console.log('Job count: ' + jobCount);
          }
        );

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.complete$.next();
    this.complete$.complete();
  }

}
```

[Browser Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvVAD.png)

Comment: I am not very familiar with Angular Elements on it's own but importing the HttpClientModule in the Service should be here as well a no go. It must be declared and imported in the (conveniently) app.module.ts file.

Comment: Seems, that you're right. See answer below. Could you pls. explain why this module needs to be imported ini app.module.ts only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `HttpClientModule` in app.module

Like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...    
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [

  ]
})
```

Comment: Wow, I had HttpClientModule already impoerted into fetch-job-data.service.ts Had no clue that it was needed in app module, too. Thnx @Adrita

Comment: You are welcome. You can remove `HttpClientModule` from impoert in data.service. Dataservice will require only HttpClient